# Dropbox.GetFileList only returns limited number of files

Tags: c#, dropbox-api

I have the following code:

```
public static void ReadAndInsertFromDropbox(string accessToken, string dropboxPath, string localPath)
{
    Dropbox db = new Dropbox(accessToken);
    List<string> allFiles = db.GetFileList(dropboxPath);
    allFiles.Sort();
    foreach (string allFile in allFiles)
    {
        string filePath = db.Download(dropboxPath, localPath, baseName);
    }
}
```

It returns a limited number of files.

I did not count the maximum number of files that it can return but it seems to be somewhere between 2,000 - 2,400.

here is the code for GetFileList:

```
public List<string> GetFileList(string dropboxfolder)
{
    List<string> l = new List<string>();
    var list = client.Files.ListFolderAsync(dropboxfolder);

    list.Wait();

    ListFolderResult listResult = list.Result;
    foreach (var item in listResult.Entries.Where(i => i.IsFile))
    {
        l.Add(item.Name);
    }
    return (l);
}
```

How do I change the code to allow downloading an unlimited number of files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListFolder` interface is paginated, meaning that you may only get a portion of the total results per single request. [The `ListFolderContinueAsync` method](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderContinueAsync.htm) should be used, in addition to [`ListFolderAsync`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm), in order to get all of the results.

You can find more information in [the `ListFolderAsync` documentation](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/html/M_Dropbox_Api_Files_Routes_FilesUserRoutes_ListFolderAsync_1.htm).